# Using REST with mnist to pull images

Tags: rest, tensorflow, grpc, tensorflow-serving, mnist

I am trying to use REST api to pull images from mnist server, similarly as this is done with a numeric [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/api_rest) (halft plus two) on the following website's example section.

In short: I am trying to replace the gRPC way of pulling the images from mnist server with REST.

Answer (score 0):

**Code for pulling/inferring the MNIST Images is shown below:**

```
!pip install -q requests

import requests

import json

headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}

json_response = requests.post('http://localhost:8501/v1/models/fashion_model/versions/1:predict', data=data, headers=headers)

predictions = json.loads(json_response.text)['predictions']

for i in range(0,3):

show(i, 'The model thought this was a {} (class {}), and it was actually a {} (class {})'.format(
    class_names[np.argmax(predictions[i])], test_labels[i], class_names[np.argmax(predictions[i])], test_labels[i]))
```

Tutorial to pull images from MNIST Server (Fashion MNIST) using REST API is available in the below link https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/serving/rest_simple#import_the_fashion_mnist_dataset

In case if there is any problem with the link provided above, you can navigate to

Tensorflow.org website -> Learn -> For Production -> Tutorials -> Serving -> Train and Serve a Model with REST.